# creating a new column from Merged columns matching a condition in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| tweet_id | image_url | doggo | floofer | puppa | puppo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | none | none | none | none |
| Second | row | doggo | none | none | none |
| third | row | none | floofer | none | none |
| fourth | row | none | none | puppa | none |
| fifth | row | none | none | none | puppo |

I have a situation trying to melt the above df columns [doggo,floofer,puppa,puppo] headers which ought to be values. I want to be able to retain the rows count and also have a new_column as table below.

| tweet_id | image_url | breed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | none |
| Second | row | doggo |
| third | row | floofer |
| fourth | row | puppa |
| fifth | row | puppo |

I already tried the pd.melt() but it doesn't return desired result. Thank you

Comment: See this: [melt() function duplicating dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73521602/14627505) (it is the recent one)

Comment: [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61575865/14627505) (2 years ago)

Comment: This is sure helpful...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### For keeping the `NaN` value in a group if all null in a group

I assume your `none` is **string**.

#### Method 1

`first_valid_index`

```
df = df.replace('none', np.nan)
df = df.set_index(['tweet_id','image_url'])

output = df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index, axis=1).reset_index()
output.columns = ['tweet_id','image_url', 'breed']
output
###
  tweet_id image_url    breed
0    First       row     None
1   Second       row    doggo
2    third       row  floofer
3   fourth       row    puppa
4    fifth       row    puppo
```

---

#### Method 2

`stack` and `first`

```
cat_type = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories=df['tweet_id'], ordered=True)
df['tweet_id'] = df['tweet_id'].astype(cat_type)
df = df.set_index(['tweet_id','image_url'])

output = df.stack().replace('none', np.nan).groupby(level=[0,1]).first().reset_index()
output.columns = ['tweet_id','image_url', 'breed']
output
###
  tweet_id image_url    breed
0    First       row     None
1   Second       row    doggo
2    third       row  floofer
3   fourth       row    puppa
4    fifth       row    puppo
```

---

#### Method 3

`melt`, `groupby()`.`apply()`

```
cat_type = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories=df['tweet_id'], ordered=True)
df['tweet_id'] = df['tweet_id'].astype(cat_type)
df.replace('none', np.nan, inplace=True)

df_melt = df.melt(id_vars=['tweet_id','image_url'], value_vars=['doggo','floofer','puppa','puppo'], var_name='breed')

output = df_melt.groupby(['tweet_id','image_url']).apply(lambda x: np.nan if x['value'].isnull().all() else x['value'].dropna().unique())
output = output.explode().reset_index()
output.columns = ['tweet_id','image_url', 'breed']
output
###
  tweet_id image_url    breed
0    First       row      NaN
1   Second       row    doggo
2    third       row  floofer
3   fourth       row    puppa
4    fifth       row    puppo
```

---

#### Discussion

I used the csv file to process,

```
df_csv = pd.read_csv('twitter-archive-enhanced.csv')
df_csv = df_csv[['tweet_id', 'source', 'doggo', 'floofer', 'pupper', 'puppo']]
df_csv = df_csv.replace('None', np.nan)

df = df_csv.set_index(['tweet_id','source']).copy()
output = df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index, axis=1).reset_index()
output.columns = ['tweet_id','image_url', 'breed']
output
###
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I actually did try it and even tried troubleshooting in a way. I keep getting _**TypeError: NDFrame.first_valid_index() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**_. A possible thing I tried was adding () to the pd.Series.first_valid_index, but gets **_AttributeError: 'Cassie' is not a valid function for 'DataFrame' object_** which is one of the row data.

Comment: As you can see, `pd.Series.first_valid_index` didn't take any argument here; How about you tryna using **Method 2**?

Comment: get's this :  _**"None of ['tweet_id'] are in the columns"**_   find attached for previewing. _[link](https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/August/59a4e958_twitter-archive-enhanced/twitter-archive-enhanced.csv)_

Comment: What is the data type of your `none`?

Comment: According to the csv file, string **None** with capital **N**, you might need to modify as `df.replace('None', np.nan, inplace=True)`

Comment: I used your CSV file to process the workflow, and it didn't stick anywhere.

Comment: Wow, this is great. Sincerely appreciate! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with pandas function, you can use a nested loop to get  the same result too.

```
df = df.replace('none', np.nan)
df = df.set_index(['tweet_id','image_url'])

result = []
for row in df.to_numpy():
    if pd.isna(row).all():
        result.append(np.nan)
    for breed in row:
        if pd.notna(breed):
            result.append(breed)
            break
            
[nan, 'doggo', 'floofer', 'puppa', 'puppo']

df['breed'] = result

df.reset_index(inplace=True)

  tweet_id image_url  doggo  floofer  puppa  puppo    breed
0    First       row    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN
1   Second       row  doggo      NaN    NaN    NaN    doggo
2    third       row    NaN  floofer    NaN    NaN  floofer
3   fourth       row    NaN      NaN  puppa    NaN    puppa
4    fifth       row    NaN      NaN    NaN  puppo    puppo
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I tried it but got **_NameError: name 'nan' is not defined_**, as a result of [nan, 'doggo', 'floofer', 'puppa', 'puppo'].

Comment: It sounds like you are assigning it as column name, I think you can update your question even though it has been closed.

Comment: And you need numpy.nan when it comes to "nan"